# finding distance between two locations

Tags: android, geolocation

I am currently developing an android app and I need some help. My app is to find the distance between the starting and destination point of a passenger. finding distance using Google map might not help because the end points and the route might not be recognized by Google map. So I need a way to find the distance traveled according to the route traveled by the person.

P.S: there are some posts regarding finding the distance using latitude and longitude but I need something to find the distance of the route followed dynamically.

Thanks all

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think that you have your answer - it just needs refinement.

Check your lat/long periodically during the trip, and calculate the distance travelled since the last check. Note the current lat/long, and repeat.

The more frequently you calculate the incremental distance travelled, the more accurate you will be, but the more battery power you will use.

Edit: You can register for periodic updates. I'd suggest starting out with once per second. See https://developer.android.com/training/location/receive-location-updates.html for an example.

Comment: I thought about that method too. But since the route might be taking a number of turns within a few seconds or so I am not clear of how frequently I should check for the position. Also is there any other way?